.Net Maui builder.Services.AddDbContext(..) not registering Services For Construction DI sqlite
the error is SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file
I need to learn how to successfully use builder.Services.AddDbContext in my Maui program. I can succesfully use the tried and true method new GlobalDbContext() my preference is to use DI Methods. I suppose I am close to learning how to do this but still do not know what i am missing.
There are others who have asked on this post  1 year later no answer still.
i am using efcore 7.0.18 and dotnet 7
What the Exception indicates is that my Db is not being Found.
When I go the non-injection route i successfully read/create the db:
Like This:

Here is my Attempt at registering the service - yields no errors or warnings (Make note Line 43):

The code at Line 41 GetConnectionString() is well Tested and reads like this:

When I consume in my ViewModel (Constructor injection) i write Code like this:

on line 145 I get Exception:
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.

at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionInternal..ctor(SqliteConnectionStringBuilder connectionOptions, SqliteConnectionPool pool)
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionPool.GetConnection()
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionFactory.GetConnection(SqliteConnection outerConnection)
Connection Strings droid
Created-ConnectionString
Data Source=/data/user/0/mil.navy.doma/files/GlobalDataBase.db
DI-ConnectionString
Data Source=/data/user/0/mil.navy.doma/files/GlobalDataBase.db
ConnectionStrings iOS
Created-ConnectionString
Data Source=/Users/mwardell/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E7D241C8-E6DF-444A-B321-624506E016E6/data/Containers/Data/Application/70874C2B-D545-413D-91BE-379C27DDA85E/Library/GlobalDataBase.db
DI-Connection-String
Data Source=/Users/mwardell/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E7D241C8-E6DF-444A-B321-624506E016E6/data/Containers/Data/Application/70874C2B-D545-413D-91BE-379C27DDA85E/Library/GlobalDataBase.db

please do not post code as images.  You've been here long enough to be aware of this rule.  What are the values of path/connection string used in the two different cases?

@Jason: Sorry the strings are the same. i was comparing on different devices

See the above Values in the main post

Okay EnsureCreated or DoMigration was still required in the Case of DI / AddDbContext.
